# how to append three lists inside a list

Tags: list, ocaml, list-comprehension

I am trying to figure out is there anyway that i can use append to make the three lists of integer inside a list to become a list of a list of integers, for example

```
[[1];[2];[3]] -> [[1;2;3]]
[] -> [[]]
[[]] -> []
```

but i am not sure how loop really in OCaml.
and the below is what i have tried, but i dont think it work

```
let rec ls (l : 'a list list) = 
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: y -> l@y
```

i have tried to use `@` to do function, but i don't how to remove the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your attempt, you never use `x` which is the head of the list, and the function is not recursive. It never calls itself. Note that `@` is never necessary in this exercise, which is good because it leads to some ugly performance implications.

Consider that you can use pattern-matching to identify whether a list is empty or not, and to extract elements from the head and the tail of a list.  What should the result of flattening an empty list be? An empty list.

```
let rec flatten =
  function
  | [] -> []
```

Now, if the first list in the list of lists is empty, it should be the result of flattening the tail. This seems pretty obvious so far.

```
let rec flatten =
  function
  | [] -> []
  | []::tl -> flatten tl
```

Now, if it's *not* empty then we can cons the first element of the first list onto the result of flattening... I'll leave that as an exercise for you to fill in.

```
let rec flatten =
  function
  | [] -> []
  | []::tl -> flatten tl
  | (x::xs)::tl -> x :: flatten ...
```

### Looping via recursion

While OCaml does have imperative loops, it is much more idiomatic, especially when dealing with lists, to loop via recursion.

In order to use recursion to loop, there must be at least one exit case where the function does *not* recursively call itself, but there must also be at least one case where it does, and that function call must in some way update the state being passed in so that it converges on the exit case.

If the exit case is passing in an empty list, the recursive calls must get closer to passing in an empty list on each call or the recursion will never end.

### If you did want to append...

If you decided you do like `@`, and don't care about O(n^2) runtime complexity, you can use it with `List.fold_left` to readily accomplish this goal.

```
# List.fold_left (@) [] [[1;2]; [3;4]];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

This is equivalent to `[] @ [1;2] @ [3;4]`.

Comment: i understand what did do, but what if i want a extra bracket like [[1;2;3;4]]

Comment: `[flatten [[1;2]; [3;4]]]`?

Comment: yeah , if i want to append them together and have two double bracket (e.g [[1;2;3;4]])

Comment: so i want to make it from a list of lists of integers to a list of a list of integers and also when the input is like [[]] -> [] or [] -> [[]]

Comment: You can wrap this up in another function which calls `flatten`. `let flatten' = function [] -> [[]] | [[]] -> [] | lst -> [flatten lst]`. Not sure what the _point_ of all of this is, but it does accomplish the goal.

Comment: But is there any way I can make it in to the sma e function